# Concat the values into a list to a key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Help me shorten the code and also print the exact same output, as the keys and values may vary every time it runs.
This is the input dictionary:

```
personal_info_list = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 32, "cars": "BMW"},
    {"id": 1, "title": "engineer", "cars": "Mercedes", "phone": "samsung"},
    {"id": 1, "cars": "Jaguar", "phone": "iphone"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Charlie", "age": 22, "phone": "iphone"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "doctor", "cars": "BMW", "phone": "samsung"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Michael", "cars": "Volkswagen", "phone": "nokia"},
    {"id": 3, "title": "doctor", "cars": "BMW", "phone": "samsung"},
]
```

The output dictionary should be like:

```
{
 1: {'name': 'John', 'age': 32, 'cars': ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Jaguar'], 'title': 'engineer', 'phone': ['samsung', 'iphone']},
 2: {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 22, 'phone': ['iphone', 'samsung'], 'title': 'doctor', 'cars': 'BMW'},
 3: {'name': 'Michael', 'cars': ['Volkswagen', 'BMW'], 'phone': ['nokia', 'samsung'], 'title': 'doctor'}
}
```

I tried the code to get the all keys of Ids and Merge it with the rest of the dicts:

```
def formatDictionary(lst_1):
    dict1={}
    for i in lst_1:
        for j in lst_1:
            temp=[]
            if i['id'] == j['id']:
                for k,v in i.items():
                    S = Merge(i,j)
            dict1[i['id']] = S 
    print(dict1)

formatDictionary(info_list)
```

Which gave me the output as:

```
{
1: {'id': 1, 'cars': 'Jaguar', 'phone': 'iphone'}, 
2: {'id': 2, 'title': 'doctor', 'cars': 'BMW', 'phone': 'samsung'}, 
3: {'id': 3, 'title': 'doctor', 'cars': 'BMW', 'phone': 'samsung'}
}
```

Comment: What is `Merge`? How does it work?

Comment: ```def Merge(d1,d2):
    d3 = d2.copy()
    d3.update(d2)
    return d3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `itertools.groupby` to get all dictionaries with the same id:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = {}
for personal_id, group in groupby(personal_info_list, itemgetter('id')):
    result[personal_id] = {'id': personal_id}
    for dct in group:
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k != 'id':
                if k in result[personal_id]:
                    if not isinstance(result[personal_id][k], list):
                        result[personal_id][k] = [result[personal_id][k]]
                    result[personal_id][k].append(v)
                else:
                    result[personal_id][k] = v
```

Here is what `result` looks like:

```
{1: {'age': 32,
     'cars': ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Jaguar'],
     'id': 1,
     'name': 'John',
     'phone': ['samsung', 'iphone'],
     'title': 'engineer'},
 2: {'age': 22,
     'cars': 'BMW',
     'id': 2,
     'name': 'Charlie',
     'phone': ['iphone', 'samsung'],
     'title': 'doctor'},
 3: {'cars': ['Volkswagen', 'BMW'],
     'id': 3,
     'name': 'Michael',
     'phone': ['nokia', 'samsung'],
     'title': 'doctor'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a less time complex solution.

Comment: @samhithgardas This is literally the best time complexity that you can reach :) It's linear with respect with the info that you provided. I.e., each piece of information is accessed only once. You can't do better than this. Please don't focus on the number of `for` cycles that you see. The first one and the second one together are still linear with respect to the number of dictionaries that you have!! Please check the documentation for `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative implementation.

```
#take the possible IDs
ids = set([d['id'] for d in personal_info_list])

r = {}
for _id in ids: #loop over the IDs and build a new dict
    for d in personal_info_list:
        if d['id'] != _id: #skip if not of interest
            continue
        if _id not in r: #init a sub-dict
            r[_id] = {}
            
        for k,v in d.items(): #populate the dict
            if k in r[_id]:
                if type(r[_id][k]) is str: #make list of values if needed
                    r[_id][k] = [r[_id][k]]
                
                if type(r[_id][k]) is list:
                    r[_id][k].append(v)
            else:
                r[_id][k] = v
```

`r` will be

```
{1: {'id': 1,
  'name': 'John',
  'age': 32,
  'cars': ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Jaguar'],
  'title': 'engineer',
  'phone': ['samsung', 'iphone']},
 2: {'id': 2,
  'name': 'Charlie',
  'age': 22,
  'phone': ['iphone', 'samsung'],
  'title': 'doctor',
  'cars': 'BMW'},
 3: {'id': 3,
  'name': 'Michael',
  'cars': ['Volkswagen', 'BMW'],
  'phone': ['nokia', 'samsung'],
  'title': 'doctor'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure is this solution explicit but for the given example it works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

res = (pd.DataFrame(personal_info_list).
       set_index('id').
       groupby('id').
       apply(lambda df: df.dropna(how='all',axis=1).T.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(),1).
             map(lambda y: y[0] if len(y)==1 else y).to_dict()).
       to_dict())

>>> res
'''
{1: {'name': 'John',
  'age': 32.0,
  'cars': ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Jaguar'],
  'title': 'engineer',
  'phone': ['samsung', 'iphone']},
 2: {'name': 'Charlie',
  'age': 22.0,
  'cars': 'BMW',
  'title': 'doctor',
  'phone': ['iphone', 'samsung']},
 3: {'name': 'Michael',
  'cars': ['Volkswagen', 'BMW'],
  'title': 'doctor',
  'phone': ['nokia', 'samsung']}}
```